# Future<void> returns widget build multiple times

Tags: flutter, dart

In my code I tried to fetch data from firebase realtime database and populate the same to my Widget but I was not able to see the data until I reload the app again. So I tried printing Hard Coded value and I'm able to see data is popping two times on screen, that might be due to multiple build. I've gone through multiple solutions but not able to fix it.

Here is my Code:

```
class CategoryHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoryHomeScreenState createState() => _CategoryHomeScreenState();
}

class _CategoryHomeScreenState extends State<CategoryHomeScreen> {

//  List<CategoriesOnly> categoriesOnlyList =[];
//  List<CategoryItems> categoryItemList = [];

  List<CategoriesOnly> categoriesOnlyList = List();
  List<CategoryItems> categoryItemList = List();
  CategoryItems categoryItems;
  CategoriesOnly categoriesOnly;
  DatabaseReference itemRef,nameRef;



@override
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    getCategoriesName();
    super.initState();


  }
  Future<void> getCategoriesName() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var userPin = prefs.getString('pin');

    var CategoryName =  FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('CategoryNames').child(userPin).once()
        .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      var key  = dataSnapshot.value.keys;
      for(var i in key)
      {
       // print(dataSnapshot.value[i]['Name']);
        CategoriesOnly categoriesOnly = new CategoriesOnly(
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['Name']
        );
        categoriesOnlyList.add(categoriesOnly);
      }

    });

    var categoryItemDetails =  FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Categories').child(userPin).once()
        .then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      var key  = dataSnapshot.value.keys;
      for(var i in key)
      {
        CategoryItems categoryItems = new CategoryItems(
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['CategoryName'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['MarketPrice'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['Name'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['OurPrice'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['TotalDiscount'],
            dataSnapshot.value[i]['Weight']

        );
        categoryItemList.add(categoryItems);
      }

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
//      statusBarColor: Colors.black, //or set color with: Color(0xFF0000FF)
//    ));
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: UI(),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
  Widget UI(){
  return Text('Hello World',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),);
  }

}
```

Comment: try use futurebuilder is preferable than do it in initState.

Comment: Hey @xion, can you share a snippet of code for futurebuilder as I'm not able get it properly.

Comment: because I don't see any `setSate` in `getCategoriesName` after all data is added in the list. alternatively, you can use `StreamBuilder`

Comment: hey @RavinderKumar, what should I set in setState method?

Answer (score 0):

I try to make it as easy to read as possible. The snippet is like below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class bla extends StatefulWidget {
  bla({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _blaState createState() => _blaState();
}

class _blaState extends State<bla> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: YourApiFunction(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return BuildYourWidgetFunction(snapshot.data);
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget BuildYourWidgetFunction(dynamic data) {
    // build your widget here
    return Container();
  }

  Future<List<YourItem>> YourApiFunction() async {
    // your firebase / any api call here
    return await YourApiCall();
  }
}
```